# Data missing after convert list to DataTable

Tags: c#

I create a new `Guid` list like this:

```
List<Guid> EmpGuid = new List<Guid>();
```

Then I populate it:

```
foreach (DataRowView list in lstTech.SelectedItems)
{
    var empGuid = (Guid)list[0];
    EmpGuid.Add(empGuid);
}
```

Once it have items I convert it to a `DataTable`:

```
var parameters = ToDataTable(EmpGuid);
```

`ToDataTable` method:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
    }

    object[] values = new object[props.Count];

    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item);
        }

        table.Rows.Add(values);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Problem is when I convert it to the `DataTable`, it creates 2 rows, but there are empty rows without my value of `EmpGuid`. Anyone have an idea why it occurs?

[image]
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just add this function and call it, it will convert List to `DataTable`.

```
 public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties

            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (Props.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
                {
                    if (GetDefault(prop.PropertyType.FullName) != null)
                    {
                        //Setting column names as Property names
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add("myColName");
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
                    if (Props.Length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
                        {
                            if (GetDefault(prop.PropertyType.FullName) != null)
                            {
                                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                                dr[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item, null) ?? GetDefault(prop.PropertyType.FullName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            //inserting property values to datatable rows
                            dr[0] = item;
                    }

                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }

            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable

            return dataTable;

        }

        public static object GetDefault(string dataType)
        {

            if (dataType.Contains("System.String"))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Boolean"))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Decimal"))
            {
                return 0.0;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.DateTime"))
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Int64"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Guid"))
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Int16"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (dataType.Contains("Int32"))
            {
                return 0;

            }
            if (dataType.Contains("System.Object"))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I try but `ItemArray` still comming null